# Read only mode in mu4e

Tags: mu4e, read-only-mode

Is there a "read only mode" in mu4e? I recently had the case to use mu4e to read emails from a system using thunderbird with maildir. I noticed that for example a file called `somemessage.eml` was renamed by mu4e to `somemessage.eml:2,S`. Then I noticed that thunderbird couldn't read this message anymore.

After renaming it back, thunderbird was able to read it again.

So, is there a way to prevent mu4e to interfer with thunderbird in this case, for example by setting it into a read only mode?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution by doing it just on os level. Using [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) you could create a "read only" view to the maildir. For example if your maildir is `~/maildir` create an empty directory `~/maildir_ro` and then do

```
bindfs --perms=a-w .maildir .maildir_ro
```

Then change `~/maildir` to `~/maildir_ro` in your init file for mu4e as well.

Comment: That's an interesting work-around! It might be worth letting the mu developer know about the issue; they might be able to add an option to mu to accommodate your use case https://github.com/djcb/mu